# Jenkinsfile/Groovy: how to use variables in regex pattern find-counts?

Tags: regex, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In the following declarative syntax pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage( "1" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          orig = "/path/to/file"
          two_lev_down = (orig =~ /^(?:\/[^\/]*){2}(.*)/)[0][1]
          echo "${two_lev_down}"
          depth = 2
          two_lev_down = (orig =~ /^(?:\/[^\/]*){depth}(.*)/)[0][1]
          echo "${two_lev_down}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...the regex is meant to match everything after the third instance of "`/`".
The first, i.e. `(orig =~ /^(?:\/[^\/]*){2}(.*)/)[0][1]` works.
But the second, `(orig =~ /^(?:\/[^\/]*){depth}(.*)/)[0][1]` does not. It generates this error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 10
^(?:/[^/]*){depth}(.*)
```

I assume the problem is the use of the variable `depth` instead of a hardcoded integer, since that's the only difference between the working code and error-generating code.

**How can I use a `Groovy` variable in a regex pattern find-count?** Or what is the `Groovy`-language idiomatic way to write a regex that returns everything after the nth occurrence of a pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `$` in front of your variable. It should be:

```
orig = "/path/to/file"
depth = 2           
two_lev_down = (orig =~ /^(?:\/[^\/]*){$depth}(.*)/)[0][1]

assert '/file' == two_lev_down
```

**Why**?

In Groovy the String-interpolation (over `GString`) works for 3 String literals:

1. usual double quotes: `"Hello $world, my name is ${name.toUpperCase()}"`
2. `Slashy`-strings used usually as regexp-literals: `/.{$depth}/`
3. Multi-line double-quoted Strings:

```
def email = """
Dear ${user}.
Thank your for blablah.
"""
```

Comment: Confirmed this works - thank you. Can you elaborate on your answer a little? There's something about Groovy language variables not quite gelling in my mind. My Groovy language learnings so far have taught me to `$`-prefix variables if they are in double-quotes, e.g. `val = 5; echo "$val"`...why was `$`-prefixing the variable `depth` necessary here when I don't have a double-quoted string?